# Prevent NodeJS dependency from logging to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I'm importing a package that frequently logs warnings to console. Is it possible to silence it?

The only solution I can think of is to unbind `console.warn` before every call to the library and then rebind it as soon as the call has been completed, but this seems janky at best. Are there any solutions that are more elegant?

Comment: Which package are you using, check if the the package have any options to disable logging.

Comment: Monkey-patch ("unbind") `console.warn` once, forever, and do all your own logging through a proper logging library (that might use the original method to actually write to stdout/stderr, but that's to be configured in a single place not all over your application)

Answer (score -3):

Just put this at the top of your code:

```js
console.warn = () => {}
```

This way will disable all warning log for a while until process exit.